# What all encryption uses == in the last?

Tags: encryption, base64

I am aware that most of the Base64 encoding has `==` at the end. Is there any other which uses does the same?

For example, I found this:

nijdRcCHIUnketWzFbcxmvqQKKDnFW05LSE3ttTjoqyBna7JT87AwxeKdoOszXYODMRm6UfA8jK97qgV8A==

But it is not a Base64 kind. What else can it be?

Comment: It's valid Base64, but what it encodes is too broad ...

Comment: Base64 is not encryption.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is impossible to determine which algorithm produced this output, because ciphertexts and hash outputs are supposed to be indistinguishable from random noise and there are *infinitely* many of them. This question doesn't have any value for future readers and we're not here to play the [guessing game](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/).

Comment: [For all we know your cat walked over your keyboard.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167136/what-type-of-encryption-is-this#comment56081754_34167136)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The string you have posted is a valid Base64 string.

A Base64 string will end with `==` if and only if the number of bytes it encodes, mod 3, equals 1.

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...   print(i, base64.b64encode(b"\x00"*i))
... 
0 b''
1 b'AA=='
2 b'AAA='
3 b'AAAA'
4 b'AAAAAA=='
5 b'AAAAAAA='
6 b'AAAAAAAA'
7 b'AAAAAAAAAA=='
8 b'AAAAAAAAAAA='
9 b'AAAAAAAAAAAA'
```

Do you see the pattern?

It happens that 16-byte (128-bit) *encryption keys* are very commonly encoded in Base64, and since 16 mod 3 = 1, their encoding will end with `==`.  But *your* string, decoded, is 61 bytes (488 bits) long.  That is too big to be most sorts of encryption key, and too *small* to be an RSA key.

This is your string, decoded, and then hexdumped:

```
00000000  9e 28 dd 45 c0 87 21 49  e4 7a d5 b3 15 b7 31 9a  |.(.E..!I.z....1.|
00000010  fa 90 28 a0 e7 15 6d 39  2d 21 37 b6 d4 e3 a2 ac  |..(...m9-!7.....|
00000020  81 9d ae c9 4f ce c0 c3  17 8a 76 83 ac cd 76 0e  |....O.....v...v.|
00000030  0c c4 66 e9 47 c0 f2 32  bd ee a8 15 f0           |..f.G..2.....|
0000003d
```

I don't see anything in there to tell me what it actually is, and `file(1)` is also stumped.  It *could* be random enough to be encrypted, but I can't tell for sure by eye.  (And if it *is* random, that doesn't mean it's encrypted!  It could just be the output of a random number generator.)

It is important to understand that **Base64 is not encryption,** because it has no key.  I didn't need to know or guess any piece of secret information to reverse the Base64 encoding of your string.  (The term 'encoding' can be confusing — it is more general.  UTF-8, Base64, and DEFLATE are all *encodings*, and so is AES-CBC, but of all of them, only AES-CBC is *encryption*.)

Comment: thanks for being so informative. Others are quite busy marking it as negative